# how to create a field for array of DBRef

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm new to MongoDB.
In my java code, I have to define a Document.
One of the fields in this Document has to contain an array of DBRef to other Document.
How can I create an array of customers?
How can it be done? what are the alternatives?

```
@DBRef
private Customer custId;
```

Thanks,
Eyal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class DBRef {
    public static void main {String args[]) {
    int customers[][] = new int [7][];
    customers[0] = new int p[];
    customers[1] = new int p[];
    customers[2] = new int p[];
    customers[3] = new int p[];
    customers[4] = new int p[];
    customers[5] = new int p[];
    customers[6] = new int p[];

    int i, j;
```

You would want to add some data to the Array. Arrays is a collection of variables of the same type, referred to by a common name. They can be one or more dimensions in java. They are use to group together related variables. For example a list of Stock price averages or a list of baseball "sports" stats. The easy ones to learn are 2D Arrays and the basic Array.

for statement